# Publishing AutoCad *.dwg files into HTML?

Tags: web-mapping, open-source-gis, software-recommendations, autocad, dwg

I'm new using Autocad. What I currently have is a dwg file generated from AutoCad 2015, now, I want to publish this file somehow into an html (web-mapping?) page so I can grab it from there and embed it into my own PHP application.

I've seen that usually the dwg files are published to [Autodesk Infrastructure Map Server](http://www.autodesk.com/products/infrastructure-map-server/overview), but it's expensive software and I want to know if there's any other solution for this, if possible, open source and free.

Comment: This question isn't very clear. In what format do you want to publish to an html page, and why would you get data from html to php -- normally php is used to create the html in the first place?

Comment: Displaying dwg in web browser?

Answer (score 2):

DWG Browser might be what you are looking for. There is a free demo of it but the program itself is not very expensive.

http://www.graytechnical.com/software/dwg-browser/

[image: dwg browser]